# Embedded Software Engineer jobs in London, UK

Tags: software-industry, united-kingdom, career-switch

I have a CS degree from a London university, but pursued a computer networking career path rather than programming.

After many years, I'm thinking of getting back into programming.

More specifically, low-level programming such as embedded systems.

I've always found that working on low-level code, learning about hardware, OS and such, more interesting than the high-level application/web development.

But I have a lot of questions about the career prospects of an embedded software career in London, UK.

Looking on all the famous job sites, I can see some embedded software jobs, but definitely much less than traditional software dev. jobs. This is expected I guess.

But does anyone with experience in the embedded software industry living in or close to London able to shed some light on things like the supply & demand of this career?

Also, what kind of prospects should I realistically expect entering this field?

From Googling, it seems most of embedded software jobs are outside of London, so as I'm not willing to spend ridiculous amounts of time commuting each day, this might be a big limitation.

Most advice online that I can find is focused on the US job market.

So I was wondering if someone could give me some general advice for the UK or ideally London area.

I'm looking for information on everything career related, progression, opportunities, whether it's a strong career path for the future, etc.

I'm not really looking for advice on the technical material and what to study etc., there's already lots of info for this stuff online.

Comment: I am actually an embedded software engineer, and the company I work for has an office in Bristol, though I am not based. For what it's worth, I consider it reasonably unlikely you're going to get information that is more specific than that from anyone else here. The only advice I'd really have is to also search for jobs involving C and C++.

Answer (score 2):

Embedded software is a bit of an odd duck, because few projects go on for a longer time, and those that do often require different skills as the project progresses, so a large part of the field is external consulting where engineers (either freelance or from a consulting firm) join projects for a limited time.

Typical projects for me, for example, would be Board Support Package projects. I'd join at a time when the hardware engineers were reasonably sure that the peripherals are properly connected, my task would be to prepare a bootloader and a programming environment in which all drivers are installed and simple applications can be loaded and debugged with a single click, and then hand that off to the application team.

So the job you are looking for doesn't exactly exist in the way you describe:

- There are consulting houses where you can have job security as they shunt you from one project to another; these aren't well paid, will be generally on a customer site or (currently) work-from-home.
- There is freelancing, which works similar to the consulting houses, except the pay is good for the time where you have work.
- There are small, owner-operated, companies that implement small projects from start to finish and require a broad set of skills. Getting a job there depends mostly on knowing the owner, pre-pandemic the best place to meet such people would be the 2m by 2m booths on trade fairs.
- There are a few companies that have mass-produced widgets that produce enough profit and require enough constant work to justify full-time engineering positions (e.g. DSL and cable modems, where new standards have to be integrated).